# How can I calculate difference between last flight and next flight?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. One is ACTUAL_FLIGHTS and other is SCHEDULED_FLIGHTS.

**ACTUAL_FLIGHTS:**

| Aircraft | Type | FLIGHT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BBQ | A320 | 26-OCT-2022 |
| AFC | A321 | 27-OCT-2022 |
| JFK | A321 | 25-OCT-2022 |
| AFC | A321 | 22-OCT-2022 |

**SCHEDULED_FLIGHTS**

| Aircraft | Type | SCHEDULE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BBQ | A320 | 28-OCT-2022 |
| AFC | A321 | 27-OCT-2022 |
| JFK | A321 | 29-OCT-2022 |
| AFC | A321 | 30-OCT-2022 |

Now I need to count number of days between last flight and the next scheduled flight for each Aircraft. Resulting table should look like this:

| Aircraft | DIFF_DAYS |
| --- | --- |
| BBQ | 2 |
| AFC | 0 |
| JFK | 4 |

I've tried this query, but didn't get intended result, even it frezees while generating result:

```
SELECT s.AC, 
       MIN(s.SCHEDULE_DATE) - MAX(f.FLIGHT_DATE)
FROM SCHEDULE_FLIGHT s
INNER JOIN FLIGHT_DATE f ON f.AC = s.AC
HAVING MIN(s.SCHEDULE_DATE) >= MAX(f.FLIGHT_DATE)
GROUP BY s.AC;
```

Comment: Oracle or Postgres? Please do not add tags for databases not used

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.AC, 
       MIN(s.SCHEDULE_DATE) - MAX(f.FLIGHT_DATE)
FROM SCHEDULE_FLIGHT s
INNER JOIN FLIGHT_DATE f 
   ON f.AC = s.AC 
  AND s.SCHEDULE_DATE >= f.FLIGHT_DATE
GROUP BY s.AC;
```

Comment: it frezees while generating result

Comment: Is it a performance issue ? Can you share the definition of the indexes which apply on your SCHEDULE_FLIGHT and FLIGHT_DATE tables ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT S.aircraft, MIN(S.schedule_date - A.flight_date) DATE_DIFF
FROM actual_flights A  INNER JOIN scheduled_flights S 
ON S.aircraft = A.aircraft 
GROUP BY S.aircraft
ORDER BY S.aircraft;
```